# How to create a search bar with a search button inside it using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, frontend

I want to create a search bar for my project which should have a search button inside it like this
[image: search bar with search button inside it]

My HTML is as follows:

```
<section id="search-section">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <h3 class="text-center pt-4">Search for Courses</h3>

          <div class="container-fluid text-center pt-3 outbox">
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col'>
                    <form class='order-1'>
                        <input type="text" class='form-control d-inline'>
                        <button class='btn btn-md btn-primary d-inline'>Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>
  </section>
```

The corresponding custom CSS used is:

```
#search-section form {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 900px;
    padding-bottom:55px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:white;
    height:50px;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .13);


}

#search-section input[type='text'] {
    width:800px;
    height:50px;
    border:none;
}
#search-section button {
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.outbox {
    height: 500px;
}
.form-control:active,
.form-control:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

The problem with my code is that it works fine on large screens but goes out of the screen for a small screen device.I want to make it such that in case of small screens the search bar should be stacked on top of the search button.

Comment: You need to define media queries for different screen sizes and breakpoints. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=media+queries&oq=media+q&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l6j69i60.2607j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I was thinking of doing so but thought there might be some bootstrap class which can make it easier

Comment: *"but thought there might be some bootstrap class which can make it easier"* with all the custom CSS used to size and position the search form and input it would be easier to just use a media query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could minimize the custom CSS (avoid setting static widths), and then use the [responsive util classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/) to position the search input and button...

```
<section id="search-section">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h3 class="text-center pt-4">Search for Courses</h3>
        <div class="container-fluid text-center pt-3 outbox">
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-11 mx-auto'>
                    <form class='order-1 d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column align-items-center'>
                        <input type="text" class='border-0 form-control h-100 mt-2 mt-sm-0'>
                        <button class='btn btn-primary mr-sm-1 mt-4 mt-sm-0 flex-fill'>Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

#search-section form {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .13);
}

.outbox {
    height: 500px;
}

.form-control:active,
.form-control:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/Zl0wdGhJVH